# Should I attend an interview for a higher salary even if I just joined a new company less than a week ago?

Tags: job-change

I just changed a job and got enrolled in my current company less than a week ago. I have already got 30% salary increase from my current company. 
However, the recruiter from another company which is my current employer's business competitor reached me and invited me to their interview. I searched online and found out that the position they want to offer usually pays 2 times more than my current salary.
My current employer and the new company are all the Big Five in our field. The salary difference is mainly because of the location. I am in a branch of the current company located in a developing country. I could work for 2 years and be transferred to the head quarters. Then I could get 3 times pay. However, if I choose to attend the interview now and lucky enough to pass it, I can immediately get the load of money.

I am pretty confident about myself. Basically, they are the same level companies. If I can pass one, I definitely can pass another one. However, I feel a moral obligation to my current employer. If I am not working for my current employer, I am pretty sure this competitor would not reach me out.  What are the potential likely consequences of accepting the new job having just accepted a promotion from my current employer?

Comment: Is the new job in a developed country? Chances are the higher pay will translate to a much higher cost of living. Twice the pay doesn't matter if it's going to cost 10 times as much to live there. As an example, a job that pays 50k a year in Lithuania is significantly better financially than a job that pays 100k a year in New York.

Comment: Yeah. The job is in Silicon Valley so I guess the cost would be much higher. I regularly spend 15,000 USD a year in my country. Have no idea how is like in Silicon Valley. Thank you for reminding me of the cost.

Comment: @deathlee You're talking about one of the most expensive places to live and work in America.  DON'T DO IT!

Comment: Difference in cost of living can be hugely significant, a previous colleague of mine moved from one of the cheapest areas of the UK to one of the most expensive and the difference basically wiped out his £14,000 wage increase!

Comment: definitely, do a cost of living analysis. The apparent massive wage increase could be, as somebody else said, a wash when you factor in just cost of housing in SV. To the underlying premise, imo, you don't owe anybody 'loyalty'. You get paid to do work, if company B finds more business value in giving you more compensation than company A, that's their call. Unless you have proprietary information or you've signed a non-compete even that isn't loyalty, it's a contract. You may 'feel' loyalty and that is a fine reason for staying somewhere, but they aren't owed it.

Comment: For reference, a studio apartment (0 bedrooms, just a room and a bathroom) in San Francisco starts at $1150/month, so you'll be spending at least $13,800 USD just for housing, not including food, transportation, etc. And that $1150/month 250 sqft place appears to be in a really bad area (School quality generally correlates well with crime rates and the general "feel" of a neighborhood, and that studio's nearest elementary school is rated 1/10). For a dedicated bedroom, you're looking at roughly $2000/month or $24,000/year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal advice, is to never make your career choices dependent on the money,  if you can afford not to.
But this also depends entirely on your goals in life. 
Which country would you rather live in, if the Job was the same and the money would be the same? What is about your social live? Which company has a better fitting culture (that one you usually only really know after some month of working there)

If you decide to change, and your current employer offers you a raise also, to keep you there, would you stay? Then stay in the First place.
If not, switch - its your live and you only get one.

Note that it is extremely bad manners to try to negotiate your salary by weaving around with another job opportunity or not taking a job you just signed a contract for. You will probably never get another offer from this company then.

Also, I would not count too much on promised career paths 2 years down the road.

Comment: +1 for the point about not choosing a job for the money. Always remember that you can't buy happiness!

Comment: It´s easier said than done - especially if you come from a developing country and you have mouths to feed. Money can´t buy happiness but it can buy you some freedom and protection